# What is the path for the "Personalize" control panel in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

What is the path for the personalize control panel in Windows 7?

Normally, these are stored as CPL files on the computer, but I can't find the CPL file for this exact functionality.

If it isn't stored as a file, can you show me what I can type in (in Run) to launch it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in `desk.cpl`, run:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,2
```

Comment: How did you figure out the path of that? Is there anywhere where I can see these forms of commands?

Comment: See http://blog.omotech.com/?p=1247

Comment: Thanks! 7 year old response, but better late than never!

Answer (score 1):

this is a shortcut to anyone else looking

- control.exe /name Microsoft.Personalization

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 ways to launch it:

1. rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,2
2. control.exe desk.cpl,,2
3. control.exe /name Microsoft.Personalization